# How to sort a text file to find anagrams in O(MN) time complexity where M is the max number of characters and N is the number of words?

Tags: python, sorting, radix-sort, counting-sort

Hi I'm new to Python and I want to find groups of anagrams in a file in linear time.Anagrams are basically two or more words which consists of the same alphabet but in different arrangements.

First I read all the words into a list. Apparently, I can use radix sort to sort each word by column and the radix sort should use a stable counting sort. But I don't know exactly what my counting sort should do? Should I write a counting sort function that takes a word and sorts it by alphabetical order? Then call it in radix sort?

Can someone give me a clearer idea on how to approach this problem?Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: It seems like radix sort could just as easily sort by character as sort by number. Maybe you should just sort each word by character alphabetically, then your list will look something like ['aab', 'aab', 'abc'] and your solution will be evident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you. It too is in O(mn)

```
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs){
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    
    HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, HashMap<ArrayList<String>>;
    
    for(String str : strs){
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            arr[str.charAt(i)- 'a']++;
        }
        
        if(map.containsKey(arr)){
            map.get(arr).add(str);
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            al.add(str);
            map.put(arr, al);
        }
    }
    
    result.addAll(map.values());
    
    return result;
}
```